# I'm not Sure why the incompatible intializer is not compatible with the parameter type int

Tags: visual-c++

Basically, I want to display my test scores and the average of them but I am unable to because of these errors

I've tried to take void display and put it in the class and declare it in main but that didn't work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class TestScore 
{
public:
    TestScore() {};
    TestScore(int arr[], int SIZE) {};
    void testAvg(int arr[], int SIZE);
    void displayArray(int arr[], int Size);

};
void TestScore::testAvg(int arr[], int SIZE)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + arr[i];
        try
        {
            if ((arr[i] > 100) || (arr[i] < 0))
            {
                throw(1);
            }
        }
        catch (int n)
        {
            cout << "Error" << endl;
        }
    }

    int average = sum / SIZE;


}

void TestScore::displayArray(int arr[], int SIZE)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}
void main()
{
    const int SIZ = 5;
    int Grade[SIZ] = { 89,65,99,100,81 };

    TestScore T(int Grade, int SIZ);
    T(Grade, SIZ).testAvg(Grade, SIZ);
    T(Grade, SIZ).displayArray(Grade, SIZ);
    system("pause");
}
```

I expect it to display the average of my score so basically, I want to have an array of 5 test scores displaying and then the average of them.

Answer (score 0):

`TestScore T(int Grade, int SIZ);` declares a function named `T`, taking two parameters of type `int`. You then call that function, passing a parameter of type `int[5]` - not an `int`. Hence the error message.

Further, that function is not implemented anywhere. Frankly, I don't understand what you are trying to do with that function declaration; it makes little sense.